# prestashop url's not working after domain change

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I moved a Prestashop (1.6) to a new domain. I see the shop at the new domain and can login in the admin panel, but al the product, categorie and other links of sub pages are not working. For all I see the message that I'm on a old link, but "'m still at the new domain.
I have changed the domain in the admin under Prefences -> SEO and URL's.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your `.htaccess` file at the root of your website to see if it has been updated with the new domain ?

If not go back to SEO and URL's and save your configuration again. If the `.htaccess` is still not updated Prestashop might not have the required rights to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Florian Lemaitre said try to do next:

1. On *Prefences -> SEO and URL's* switch Off and then On "Friendly URL", it will regenerate your .htaccess file.
2. On *Performance* tab clear Smarty cache.